# Issue with closing login window and pop-up ads on makeMyTrip.com affecting homepage access

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am experiencing difficulties closing the login window and pop-up ads that are preventing me from accessing the homepage on makeMyTrip.com

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    // Create EdgeOptions and configure to block ads
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // Disable extensions to block ads

    driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("Tear down");
    driver.quit();
}

public void clickAction(By elementLocator) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(elementLocator);
    action.moveToElement(webElement).click().build().perform();
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void clickMakeMyTripLogo() {
    clickAction(By.xpath("//a[@data-cy='mmtLogo']"));
}

@Test(priority = 2)

public void blocksadd() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement adds = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//i[@class='wewidgeticon we_close']")));
    adds. Click();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pop-up is placed inside `iframe`, so to close it, you should switch context to that frame.

```java
public void closeBlocksAdd() {
        WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement popupIframe = wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ByCssSelector("[id*=notification-frame]")));
        driver.switchTo().frame(popupIframe);
        WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='wewidgeticon we_close']"));
        close.click();
        wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(close));
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```